# Discord API - get messages before a date from a channel

Tags: discord.py

I want to implement a command in my bot, to allow fetching messages from a channel and process them further.

I tried to look for how to fetch messages from a specific channel, but could not find an explicit answer to it, except most of the forum pages simply refer to the API page, with some saying trying the `discord.utils.get` method.

I am wondering if it would be something like this, but I could not find the matching methods/attributes that I can use to do this:

```
@bot.command(name='fetchmessages', help='....')
async def fetchmessages(ctx, from_channel_id:str, from_date:str):
    #check if the channels already exist       
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=from_channel_id)
    from_date = .... #code to parse the string to a date object
        
    discord.utils.get(channel.messages, # Q1
            from=from_date)             # Q2
    ####
```

However, I cannot really do this because

- Q1: assuming the channel is a `TextChannel` [link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel), the class does not have an attribute that gives me all the messages from that channel, but only `last_message`. While `TextChannel` has a method `fetch_message` but that only gets a single message with an ID parameter
- Q2: I am not sure if I can pass a date object like this, because the API for `discord.utils.get` does not explicitly say what attributes (`**attrs`) can be specified.

Any hints much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that you can't use `fetch_message` because it only returns a single message, but you can use `channel.history` (link can be found **[here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history)**)

```py
from datetime import datetime

@bot.command()
async def fetchmessages(ctx, from_channel_id:str, from_date:str):
    channel = client.get_channel(int(from_channel_id))
    date = datetime.strptime(from_date, '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
    messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=200, after=date).flatten()
    
    #To do something with messages
```

Referenced this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)** regarding string to datetime object.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: you can use the [channel.history()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=channel%20messages#discord.TextChannel.history) function but for that, you would have to have the read_message_history permissions to get access to those messages
Q2: as you can read in [discord.utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=channel%20messages#discord.utils.get) "To have a nested attribute search (i.e. search by x.y) then pass in x__y as the keyword argument." you can access whatever variable you want but instead of using '.' you need to use '_'
so for example

```py
discord.utils.get(channel.messages,created_at=from_date)
```

another thing that I just want to point out is the date attribute you're trying to get by has to be a datetime.datetime object